# How to download a file from selenium python when calling ng-click

Tags: javascript, python, angular, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to emulate to download a file from a website using Selenium Python when clicking a button that is defined with ng-click.

The HTML file has this content:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 btn-group">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" ng-click="exportToExcel('#exportable')" class="btn-text btn-link export-main" value="Export" />
</div>
```

The code that I put  after checking different options is not doing anything.

I

When I use the Selenium IDE, the only step recorded is to "click" on the "css=btn-text" element and that works, but with the chrome driver and Selenium in Python nothing is being downloaded.

I have this code to make sure that Chrome Driver downloads a file. (I have tested with other sites and this works)

```
 options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
          prefs = {'download.default_directory' : self.download_location,
              'download.prompt_for_download': False,
              'download.directory_upgrade': True,
              'safebrowsing.enabled': False,
              'safebrowsing.disable_download_protection': False}
          options.add_argument('--headless')
          options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
          driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, 
                                   service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=/tmp    /chromedriver.log'])
```

Here is the code that I am using to click on the button to download the file:

```
export_button = WebDriverWait(self.webdriver,10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "export-main"))) 

 ActionChains(self.webdriver)\
  .click(export_button)\
  .move_to_element(export_button)\
  .perform()
```

I would expect to download the excel file in the designated folder to the Chrome Driver, but it seems that Selenium and Angular don't play well together.

Is there other way to call the "ExportToExcel" function using Javascript?

Comment: Try this.See if it helps `export_button = WebDriverWait(self.webdriver,10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.export-main")))`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried but it did not work.

Comment: what error are you getting? any stack trace?

Comment: to simply answer your question about calling `ExportToExcel` using javascript, just run `driver.execute_script("exportToExcel('#exportable');")`. i don't know if this will download your file, but that is how you execute javascript within webdriver.

Comment: @KunduK   I don't get any stack trace. No errors. I just get the debug statements from the Chrome Driver in /tmp/chromedriver.log but I don't see any errors in the log (no stack trace at the point of the call.  Is there any way to debug more the webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

not being able to test this myself, since every website is different, you might be able to call the javascript function you are asking about. Selenium allows you to execute javascript from within webdriver pretty easily. this can be done with

```
driver.execute_script("exportToExcel('#exportable');")
```

I don't know if this will download your file, but that answers your question of how you execute javascript within webdriver. again, whether or not this will download a file depends on many other circumstances that can't be determined from your post without having more information.

Comment: The "exportToExcel" is an Angular function and when I put this command it complains that the function does not exist.


Below is the log from the chrome driver:


`[1554990242.867][INFO]: [60f33b385dd98a5ff18a450760d13d7e] COMMAND ExecuteScript {
   "args": [  ],
   "script": "exportToExcel('#exportable')",
   "sessionId": "60f33b385dd98a5ff18a450760d13d7e"
}`



` 1554990242.870][INFO]: [60f33b385dd98a5ff18a450760d13d7e] RESPONSE ExecuteScript ERROR javascript error: exportToExcel is not defined`

Comment: Maybe the Javascript functions are not loaded at the time of the call? How I can assure the complete DOM is loaded?

Comment: @juanv honestly, without any reproducible  code, we aren't really able to help. everything is just speculations at this point. you have the code for creating your driver instance, locating the button, and waiting for the button, but we have no clue what else is going on with the site since we don't know what the site even is.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to the problem:

just call the javascript to click on the "export button" like this:

```
self.webdriver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", export_button)
```

Comment: how? im trying but its not working